# EC2 - can ssh but cannot access to a web page server by Nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssh

I setup my ECS instance with my own VPC, with its own Security Group (:22/:80/:443 open).
Gateway everything is working.

I can ssh to my server with the public IP.

But I cannot serve a simple HTML page with Nginx. I use the config I had on my own server but I cannot reach my page.

Nothing fancy in my Nginx config :

```
server {
       listen           80;
       listen           [::]:80;
       server_name      www.gfelot.xyz gfelot.xyz;
   root /var/www/siteWeb;

   index index.html;

   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }


#       location ~ /.well-known {
#                allow all;
#                }
}
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check firewall rules and SELinux setting on VPC server.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu with ufw enabled. Even if I disable it I got the same result.

Comment: are you able to telnet port 80 from your computer